# What's the significance of a parameter in a function call when using gulp 4 .series?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to understand more about running gulp4 tasks in a serial manner. One answer that was given to me was this:

```
gulp.task('make-prod-ex1', gulp.series(
    function(done) {
        makeAppHtml('app/**/*ex1', done);
    }, 
    'makeTemplate',
    'clean-css',
    'make-css-files',
    'make-css-bundle',
    'rename-css-bundle',
    'clean-js',
    'make-js-bundle',
    'rename-js-bundle',
    'rename-index',
     function (done) {
        console.log("Completed");
        done();
     }));
```

Something I don't understand is what is the significance of the word `done` here.

Why is there a `done` in the first function call, why is it an argument of makeAppHtml and why is it used again in the last function call but this time with a () after it?

Note that I did check the gulp docs and again I see so many uses of the word done but I don't know why its there:

```
   https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpseriestasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done` it's callback which informs the gulp that the task is finished.

Any gulp task can be written by two ways:

```
gulp.task('default', () {
  return gulp
    .src(...)
    .pipe(anyGulpPlugin())
    .dest(...);
});
```

Or so:

```
gulp.task('default', done => {
  gulp
    .src(...)
    .pipe(anyGulpPlugin())
    .dest(...)
    .on('end', done);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't really understand. For example why does the person who answered my question have makeAppHtml('app/**/*ex1', done); a done as the second argument and what would the simplest makeAppHtml function you could code look like?

Comment: What function `makeAppHtml` does? Could you add it content in the question?

Comment: Actually I now understand your answer. I was getting confused with the done => .   Thank you for taking the time to answer my question I will accept it now. Now I just need to learn how to get Gulp 4 using the package.son so I made another question about that.

Comment: Np, `done =>` it's arrow function definition accessible in ES6.